# Remove the last line from the text file (including empty lines) using batch

Tags: batch-file

My text file

```
Header
A,B,C,D,E
F,G,H,I,J
K,L,M,N,O
Footer
```

I want remove the Footer and also empty lines below Footer (Empty lines are not static) And my expected output

```
Header
A,B,C,D,E
F,G,H,I,J
K,L,M,N,O
```

I tried the below code, But it removing the last empty line alone.

```
set row=
for /F "delims=" %%j in (file.txt) do (
  if  defined row echo.!row!>> newfile.txt
  set row=%%j
)
```

Comment: What is an "empty line" for you? `for /F` ignores empty lines, so your code should work. Or do the lines following the footer contain one or more spaces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be a generic way to perform the task; *If you want something different consider providing more specific information and example file(s)*:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "SrcFile=file.txt"

If Not Exist "%SrcFile%" Exit /B
Copy /Y "%SrcFile%" "%SrcFile%.bak">Nul 2>&1||Exit /B

(   Set "Line="
    For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("%SrcFile%.bak") Do (
        SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        If Defined Line Echo !Line!
        EndLocal
        Set "Line=%%A"))>"%SrcFile%"
EndLocal
Exit /B
```

You should change your filename on line `4` to match your actual source file's name. If you are happy with the result you can optionally delete the `.bak` file, *(which is a backup of the original file, saved for safety)*.

***Note:*** The resultant file will end with the normal `CRLF`, (i.e there will be a blank line at the bottom).

Answer (score 3):

What about a simple:

```
FINDSTR /R /I /V "^$ Footer" file.txt>>newfile.txt
```

?

1. /R means regexp
2. /I means case insensitive
3. /V means EXCLUDE matches, instead of showing

in the double quotes are (separated by space) all the regexps that will be applied:

1. ^$ matches empty lines
2. Footer matches the exact word Footer

Comment: very fast way to remove the last line of a text file. GREAT.

Answer (score 1):

pretty straight forward: read until you hit the footer, then quit (removes the Footer and anything after):

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%j in (file.txt) do (
  echo %%j|findstr /b "Footer" >nul && goto :done
  echo %%j>> newfile.txt
)
:done
```